# Accessing to a different computer's OpenNI camera device using python

Tags: python, camera, raspberry-pi2, openni, asus-xtion

I have a ASUS Xtion Pro-Live camera. It is connected to a raspberry pi. I have written a python code which grabs frames from the camera, displays and saves.

```
def get_frames():
    capture = cv2.VideoCapture(cv.CV_CAP_OPENNI)
    capture.set(cv.CV_CAP_OPENNI_IMAGE_GENERATOR_OUTPUT_MODE, cv.CV_CAP_OPENNI_VGA_30HZ)

    while(True):
            if not capture.grab():
                print "Unable to Grab Frames from camera"
                break
            okay, color_image = capture.retrieve(0, cv.CV_CAP_OPENNI_BGR_IMAGE)
            if not okay:
                print "Unable to retrieve Color Image from device"
                break

            cv2.imshow("rgb camera", color_image)
            name = "images/" + str(time.time()) + ".png"
            cv2.imwrite(name, color_image)
            if cv2.waitKey(10) == 27:
                break

    capture.release()
```

I want to use the similar code on my computer. But in this case, basically I need to access to the raspberry pi, and use the camera which is connected to raspberry pi. I need to get real time video data from the camera in the similar way, and use it on my code.

How can I manage to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're only using the RGB stream which shouldn't be a huge amount of data. If you're planning to stream depth+RGB you should look for a way to compress the data before sending it on the network, then decompressing it at the other end.

I remember this is a problem people have been tacking when the kinect came out.
For example, check out Fabrizio Pece's paper on [Adapting standard video codecs for depth streaming](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/F.Pece/publications/pdfs/adapting-standard-video-codecs-for-depth-streaming.pdf) (pdf).
You should be able to find similar papers and implementations.

If you're not interested in streaming depth and using RGB only, more like a webcam, I imagine there are python libraries that will allow you to create an HTTP or RTP stream from your Raspberry PI which you can then read on your other computer.